# Duplicate value in a postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to modify a table inside my PostgreSQL database, but it says there is duplicate! what is the best way to find a duplicate value inside a table? kinda a select query?

Comment: Oh, it wasn't me that gave it. You'd have to be deliberately malevolent in order to get *me* to give a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to change a value in a column that is part of the `PRIMARY KEY` or has a `UNIQUE` constraint and get this error there, then you should be able to find the conflicting row by

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE conflicting_column = conflicting_value;
```

If conflicting_value is a character type, put it in single quotes (`'`).

**EDIT:** To find out which columns are affected by the constraint, check [this post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2002-05/msg00304.php).

Comment: i dont know the conflicting_value! i just "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_audit_log_pkey"

Answer (score 14):

Try Like This

```
SELECT count(column_name), column_name 
from table_name 
group by column_name having count(column_name) > 1;
```

Comment: what it is supposed to do? i get 0 rows!

Comment: This query is the expected answer, I have the same problem as OP and this query shows me the records which are duplicated. Deleting them allowed me to create the index.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, determine which fields in your table have to be unique.  This may be something marked as a Primary Key, a unique index based on one or more fields or a check constraint, again based on one or more fields.

Once you've done that, look at what you're trying to insert and work out whether it busts any of the unique rules.

And yes, SELECT statements will help you determine what's wrong here.  Use those to determine whether you are able to commit the row.